# NextJS children components cannot display data

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem where I am trying to show array of data to render a `<ul> <li>` element. In the code below the console logs are working fine, but the list items aren't appearing. This is my code

if I put the loop before the `<Dashboard>`, the data can appear. but if the data is entered into `<Dashboard>` the data does not appear

parent component as `components/dashboard/Dashboard.jsx`

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';
import {useState} from 'react';

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(true);
  const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState(props.pageTitle);
  const [children, setChildren] = useState(props.children);
  const toggleSidebar = () =>{
    setShowSidebar(!showSidebar);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/logo.png" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Show Data"
        />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content="/images/logo.png"
        />
        <meta name="og:title" content={siteTitle} />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content={siteTitle} />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="Website" />
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
      </Head>
        <Sidebar showSideBar={showSidebar}/>
        <Header onClick={toggleSidebar} showSideBar={showSidebar}/>
        <div className={'main main-app p-3 p-lg-4 '+(showSidebar ? '' : 'main-minify')}>
          {/* call children component */}
          {children}
          <Footer/>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

children components as `pages/index.jsx`

```
import {Dashboard, DashboardBrand} from '../../components/dashboard/'
import {CardSiteOverview, Card} from '../../components/card/'
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const HomePage = () => {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState();
  const onGridReady = async() => {
      await fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json',{
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => {
          setRowData(data);
      })
      .catch(function(error){
          console.log(error)
      })
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    onGridReady();
  },[])

return (
  <>
    <Dashboard pageTitle="Dashboard">
      <Card title="Data Show">
         <ul>
         {/* console.log show in inspect element, but html element not show */}
         {console.log(rowData)}
         {rowData ? rowData.map((item, i)=>{
            return(<li key={i}>{item.athlete}</li>)
         }) : ""}
         </ul>
      </Card>
    </Dashboard>
  </>
)
}
export default HomePage;
```

the data can appear if like this

```
return (
  <>
    <ul>
      {rowData ? rowData.map((item, i)=>{
        return(<li key={i}>{item.athlete}</li>)
       }) : ""}
    </ul>
    <Dashboard pageTitle="Dashboard">
      <Card title="Data Show">
         {/* console.log show in inspect element, but html element not show */}
         {console.log(rowData)}
      </Card>
    </Dashboard>
  </>
)
```

please help me to how to fix the problem. thank you

Comment: Why would you store children in useState?

Comment: can you tell me the best practice for storing data in children's components? @Gasanov

Comment: You don't. You want to store `rowData` that you get in your `HomePage`. It will be passed as `props.children` to your `Dashboard` and rendered nicely, without any intermediate states.

Comment: Is the Card Component render {children} inside it?

Comment: share your Card Component code. The problem might lie there.